# Is there any other option to connect to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-connector

0   I'm a newbie to snowflake and trying to connect to the db using python but when executing the code i get this error "snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 251005: Password is empty"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Pre steps: Install Snowflake Python connector using pip command or conda installer
are easiest as the package is installed along with dependent packages.

pip command: *pip install snowflake-connector-python*

conda installer command: *conda install -c conda-forge snowflake-connector-python*

Refer Snowflake official documentation for more details
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html

Setting Snowflake Session Parameters -
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html

Above link can be referred for supplying Passwords to the Python program using different ways.